# Как дописывать в текстовый файл с новой строки?

Tags: c#

Записываю с одного файла текст в другой. Все ок, ну только как дописывать в файл при каждом обращении.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    timec = new Timer(10000);//здесь интервал таймера
    timec.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timec_Elapsed);
    timec.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
private static void timec_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{

    // Проверка существования файла.
    if (File.Exists("C:\\0.txt"))
    {
       var m = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\0.txt");
       File.WriteAllLines("C:\\log.txt", m);

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Файла нет!");
        // Создаем файл.
        File.Create("C:\\0.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("файл создан");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: кстати, строки `"C:\\log.txt"` можно записывать как `@"C:\log.txt"`. избавляет от возможных ошибок и не так режет глаз.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте писать через `File.AppendAllLines` или `File.AppendAllText`. Файл создается автоматически.

```
const string SourceFile = "C:\\0.txt";
const string LogFile = "C:\\log.txt";

private static void timec_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(SourceFile))
    {
       var lines = File.ReadAllLines(SourceFile);
       File.AppendAllLines(LogFile, lines);
    }
}
```